# In app purchase (IOS and Android) for app having its own authentication

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, in-app-purchase

I would like to implement an in-app purchase in an existing xamarin forms app that already have it's own authentication system. Is that possible? How can I understand if the logged in user is the one that purchased the product as the purchase is done at Google/Apple Account level? Is there a standard way to deal with this situation? I didn't found any doc about that.

Comment: When you process the purchase you update the users account in your server to record the purchase.

Comment: So, you are asserting there is no limitations in terms of authentication in an app purchase for both IOS and Android? Apple and Google does not have any restriction in this terms?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I believe that Google Play Store makes it easier to associate a purchase with a user. With iOS you need to record the transaction id from the receipt against the user account. If another user presents the same id you can either decline to activate the purchase or remove the purchase from the other account and move it to the new user account.

Comment: My worries is that Google and Apple have some restriction in terms of authentication used for In App Purchase . If I understood well once I'm logged in the App using my custom authentication there is no problem performing any In App purchase usign either Google or IOS Account.

Comment: The user will need to log in using their iTunes/google play account to complete the purchase. I know on iOS you cannot force a user to register/login with your own account system just to use IAP. Registration/login  must be optional